# Awesomium don't works under Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, awesomium

Who knows why awesomium component (c# project) does not load the page if it is running in the operating system (windows 7/8) under virtualbox?

Comment: Same problem here, The more weird thing is it works if I put a brakepoint in the form constructor!

Comment: How many processor cores have you set up in your vm? @armanradan

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have set at least 2 processor cores in your VM. Awesomium has some problems with loading content in virtual machines having only one core